# en muchos tutoriales pueden definir elementos en cualquier momento (problemas con botones prev y fav) audio player

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola compañeros, espero de todo corazón se encuentren muy bien.
Me disculpo de antemano por esta ser una pregunta un poco menos concreta, de hecho si llego a faltar el reglamento del foro la eliminare inmediatamente. dicho lo cual paso al problema.
el problema que tengo es que en un proyecto de aprendizaje autodidáctico he estado intentando crear un reproductor de audio en python con la librería tkinter y pygame, ya funcionan muchos de los botones como el play o el pause pero no logro hacer funcionar los botones de prev y next (anexo el código por si le quieren dar un vistazo), sin embargo en muchos de los tutoriales observo que usan código que no han definido previamente (anexo imágenes tanto de mi código como del ejemplo que les comento), espero sin el afán de molestar puedan ayudarme a resolver mi duda o ayudarme a resolver el problema de mi código.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

````
import fnmatch
import os
from typing import Pattern
from pygame import mixer


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tejon's Bar player")
window.geometry("900x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.config(bg='black')

rootpath="C:\\Users\\Victor\\Music\\mi musica"
Pattern="*mp3"

mixer.init()

def play_next():
    next_song=listBox.curselection()
    next_song=next_song[0]+1
    next_song_name=listBox.get(next_song)
    label.config(text=next_song_name)

mixer.music.load(rootpath + "\\" + next_song_name)
mixer.music.play()

listBox.select_clear(0, 'end')
listBox.activate(next_song)
listBox.select_set(next_song)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootpath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, Pattern):
        listBox.insert('end', filename)




window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Podrías explicar qué significa *"usan código que no han definido previamente"*? Si no has escrito el código... cómo lo usas? Y si lo has escrito, no está definido ya? No entiendo. Además, cuál es tu pregunta? Solo afirmas que "en muchos tutoriales usan código que no han definido" pero no veo ningún problema o error. Por favor, especifica qué es lo que pasa. Lo que veo así por encima es que intentas utilizar en el `mixer` la variable `next_song_name` que has definido dentro de un método... eso jamás va a estar disponible fuera de él. Define la variable fuera del método o devuélvela en él.

Comment: Recuerda que no se puede aprender a correr antes de caminar, y no vas a caminar sin antes ir a gatas. Repasa lo básico, aprende a declarar variables, modificarlas y *devolverlas* en los métodos. Repasa la teoría de los bloques de código (una variable nunca va a estar disponible fuera de su *scope*). Para programar es muy importante tener una buena base antes de empezar a hacer cosas más grandes, que si no luego se cogen muy malos hábitos